# Prevent Environment Variables From Being Treated as String Literals

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

Consider the following `.env` ([dotenv](https://rubygems.org/gems/dotenv)) file with content

```
FOO="hello\nworld"
```

and script `test.rb`

```
require 'dotenv/load'

puts ENV['FOO']
puts ENV['BAR']
```

Running `BAR="hello\nworld" ruby test.rb` results in the following output:

```
hello
world
hello\nworld
```

How can I prevent `ENV['BAR']` from being treated as a string literal? My actual use case is  passing environment variables to a Rakefile with [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/), and no matter what I do, I can't get newlines passed to my script. Local development with a `.env` file works fine.

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dotenv](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dotenv/2.2.1/file/README.md#Multi-line_values) is parsing environment variables differently than ruby's ENV module.  You can see in the dotenv docs they call out the special behavior with newlines [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dotenv/2.2.1/file/README.md#Multi-line_values).

> If you need multiline variables, for example private keys, you can
>   double quote strings and use the \n character for newlines:
>
> PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nHkVN9…\n-----END DSA
>   PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

If you're using bash or zsh, you can create your environment variables on the command line using [shell quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings):

```
BAR=$'hello\nworld'
```

The output of your program then is:

```
▶ BAR=$'hello\nworld' ruby dotenv.rb
hello
world
hello
world
```